# How to select a tf-serving version?

Tags: tensorflow-serving

If I use tenserflow 1.8 or tensorflow 1.12, which version of tf-version I can use for inference?
Is it have a requirement that if I use tenserflow 1.8 then I should choose corresponding tf-serving r1.8?
Or we just use the master branch is ok?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's best to use the version of TF Serving that corresponds to the version of TensorFlow your model was trained with. You can check out the releases of TF Serving on [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/releases).